# is it posible to force any ie version to FF view using <meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible"?

Tags: html, browser, cross-browser

I was googling, about how to fix compability problem ....
and i get this to force ie8 to latest version ie

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;/>
```

in my mind ...
is it posible to force any user agent.
let say from any browser to firefox

example `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="FF=edge;/>` or else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heh, clever thjnking! :) But no, this is not possible.

The `X-UA-Compatible` header is proprietary, and can be used only to switch between various versions of the same browser engine (At the moment, it is supported only by IE, as far as I know).

You'll have to go the hard route and adjust the CSS so it works in all browsers (or serve different style sheets for different browsers).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this line works also for non IE browsers, for example you can use something like this

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />`

to force the use of Chrome rendering if available, or the last verison of IE of not. This code is completely valid but I'm not 100% sure what it means and what it really does :)

I have done some google research but I haven't found nothing concrete about it so I think is not a good idea relying only on this line of code for cross-browser compatibility. Personally I insert this code on my sites because it can do no harm :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Chrome rendering will only be available if the browser has the Chrome frame plug-in installed, which it usually won't be. http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/